# RDLC tablix colspan equivalent

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

Is their some sort of colspan equivalent for the RDLC markup? I of course tried colspan and the report doesn't render in design view then, deserialaztion error. The project and zipfile are much longer than the single column to display.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was to select all the cells, right click and choose merge cells.

Answer (score 1):

To do this using markup, try:

```
<TablixCell>
  <CellContents>
    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle1">
    ...
    </Rectangle>
    <ColSpan>2</ColSpan>
  </CellContents>
</TablixCell>
```